# Scrapy: How to scrape a product price which consists of two parts?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I got a scraper which collects data from the website "www.bol.com", the only problem I stumbled upon so far is that the price consists of two parts (in the HTML source). The number and the fraction of the number is seperated.

I tried scraping both the price and the fraction of the price seperately. This works, however, not every product has a price with a fraction. So my scraper ended up only scraping all the products with prices which consist of a number and a fraction, and not the numbers without a fraction. Maybe I need to return the number "0" when there's no fraction available?

**HTML Source for price with fraction**

The price is being displayed as: 777,86

```
<span class="promo-price" data-test="price">777
  <sup class="promo-price__fraction" data-test="price-fraction">86</sup>
</span>
```

Source: https://www.bol.com/nl/p/apple-iphone-11-64gb-zwart/9200000119815601/?bltgh=j0qmNqgyvLwjCGWgGxxPmA.1_30.31.ProductTitle

**HTML Source for price without fraction**

The price is being displayed as 739-  (I don't need the - symbol)

```
<span class="promo-price" data-test="price">739
  <sup class="promo-price__fraction  promo-price__fraction--dash" data-test="price-fraction">-</sup>
</span>
```

Source: https://www.bol.com/nl/p/apple-iphone-xr-64gb-zwart/9200000098453451/?bltgh=j0qmNqgyvLwjCGWgGxxPmA.1_30.33.ProductTitle

**Scraper**

```
import scrapy
from ..items import Mobile

class AmazonScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bol_scraper"

    # How many pages you want to scrape
    no_of_pages = 1

    # Headers to fix 503 service unavailable error
    # Spoof headers to force servers to think that request coming from browser ;)
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.2840.71 Safari/539.36'}

    def start_requests(self):
        # starting urls for scraping
        urls = ["https://www.bol.com/nl/l/apple-iphones/N/4010+4294862300/?ruleRedirect=1&sI=iphone&variants="]

        for url in urls: yield scrapy.Request(url = url, callback = self.parse, headers = self.headers)

    def parse(self, response):

        self.no_of_pages -= 1

        # print(response.text)

        mobiles = response.xpath("//a[@class='product-title px_list_page_product_click']").xpath("@href").getall()

        # print(len(mobiles))

        for mobile in mobiles:
            final_url = response.urljoin(mobile)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=final_url, callback = self.parse_mobile, headers = self.headers)
            # break

        if(self.no_of_pages > 0):
            next_page_url = response.xpath("//ul[@class='pagination']/li[@class='[ pagination__controls pagination__controls--next ]']/a").xpath("@href").get()
            final_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url = final_url, callback = self.parse, headers = self.headers)

    def parse_mobile(self, response):
        title = response.xpath("//span[@class='h-boxedright--xs']//text()").get() or response.xpath("//h1[@class='page-heading']//text()").get()
        rawprice = '.'.join(response.css('.promo-price ::text').extract())
        cleanprice = rawprice.replace('-','00').replace('\n', '').replace(' ','')
        price = cleanprice[:-1]


        print(title, price, price_fraction)


        yield Mobile(title = title.strip(), price = price.strip(), price_fraction = price_fraction.strip())
```

**Result before cleaning the data**

```
{"title": "Apple iPhone 11 - 64GB - Zwart", "price": "777\n  .86."},
{"title": "Apple iPhone Xs - 64GB - Goud", "price": ""},
{"title": "Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max - 256GB - Spacegrijs", "price": "1319\n  .-."},
{"title": "Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max - 512GB - Goud", "price": "1589\n  .-."},
{"title": "Apple iPhone 11 - 256GB - Zwart", "price": "899\n  .-."},
{"title": "iPhone Xs Max - 64GB - Space Grey", "price": "849\n  .-."},
{"title": "Apple iPhone Xs - 64GB - Zilver", "price": "752\n  .-."},
{"title": "Apple iPhone XR - 128GB -  Zwart", "price": "716\n  .45."},
{"title": "Apple iPhone 11 Pro - 64GB - Middernachtgroen", "price": "1199\n  .-."},
{"title": "Apple iPhone 8 - 64GB - Spacegrijs", "price": "535\n  .12."},
{"title": "Apple iPhone 11 - 128GB - Zwart", "price": "833\n  .-."},
{"title": "Apple iPhone XR - 64GB - Zwart", "price": "739\n  .-."},
{"title": "Apple iPhone Xs - 64GB - Spacegrijs", "price": "745\n  .58."},
{"title": "Apple iPhone 7 - 32GB - Spacegrijs", "price": "378\n  .95."}
```

**Result after cleaning the data**

```
{"title": "Apple iPhone 11 - 64GB - Zwart", "price": "777.86"},
{"title": "Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max - 256GB - Spacegrijs", "price": "1319.00"},
{"title": "Apple iPhone Xs - 64GB - Goud", "price": ""},
{"title": "Apple iPhone Xs - 64GB - Zilver", "price": "752.00"},
{"title": "Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max - 512GB - Goud", "price": "1589.00"},
{"title": "Apple iPhone 11 - 256GB - Zwart", "price": "899.00"},
{"title": "iPhone Xs Max - 64GB - Space Grey", "price": "849.00"},
{"title": "Apple iPhone XR - 128GB -  Zwart", "price": "716.45"},
{"title": "Apple iPhone 8 - 64GB - Spacegrijs", "price": "535.12"},
{"title": "Apple iPhone 11 Pro - 64GB - Middernachtgroen", "price": "1199.00"},
{"title": "Apple iPhone Xs - 64GB - Spacegrijs", "price": "745.58"},
{"title": "Apple iPhone 11 - 128GB - Zwart", "price": "833.00"},
{"title": "Apple iPhone XR - 64GB - Zwart", "price": "739.00"},
{"title": "Apple iPhone 7 - 32GB - Spacegrijs", "price": "378.95"}
```

Comment: I don't see where you are scraping the fraction value - does that just happen in your `price = ...` line? If so I would just test `if price.endsWith('-')` and then remove the last character before parsing it as a number

Comment: So what exactly is your desired output, given your two sample htmls?

Comment: @JackFleeting
I edited my code above with the results. For the output I would like to have one decimal (price + fraction) so that it can be exported as one decimal to a data set. If there is a price without a fraction, I'd like the fraction to be double zero.

Comment: So the parse_mobile function terminates if the fraction is selected via xpath but not in the response? Try passing `default=0` to the .get() function where you select the fraction

Comment: @Taxel Mhm, I understand what you are saying.. I think. But I'd have no clue where I'd set that default value to 0? I am quite new to this.. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe

```
price = '.'.join(response.css('.promo-price ::text').extract())
```

Your mistake is using `.get()` function which picks only first text chunk found, while there are two to extract.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it resulted in quite a dirty result but I managed to clean the data with a few replaces (see code above). Maybe there's a better way to clean it properly?

Answer (score 2):

Using your two html samples as basis, take a look at this and try to modify it to your own code:

```
pricing = """
<prices>
  <unit>
  <span class="promo-price" data-test="price">777
  <sup class="promo-price__fraction" data-test="price-fraction">86</sup>
</span>
  </unit>
  <unit>
    <span class="promo-price" data-test="price">739
  <sup class="promo-price__fraction  promo-price__fraction--dash" data-test="price-fraction">-</sup>
</span>
  </unit>
</prices>

"""

from scrapy.selector import Selector
sel = Selector(text=pricing)
prices = sel.xpath('//span[@class="promo-price"]').extract()
for price in prices:
    sel = Selector(text=price)    
    fract = sel.xpath('.//text()').extract()
    full = sel.xpath('//span/text()').extract()
    price = full[0].strip() + '.' + fract[1].strip().replace('-','00')
    print(price)
```

Output:

```
777.86
739.00
```

Comment: Jack, thank you very much for your answer, this solution worked as well. I went with the option below (from Michael) though. I appreciate it!